# How does on"XYZ" callback event work?

Tags: android, events, event-handling, callback

I'm looking for concept explanations or example code, if possible

I'm new to (android) development and from what i've seen, there are a ton of "onEvent()" methods. for example, View.onClickListener(), onPageDownload, onProgressUpdate... i've noticed that everything starts with "on", and i'm assuming that it implies the method is a callback event? is that the same thing as a handler?

i have a hard time understanding how events work, and what's the best way to make my own event handler.

say i want to make a handler `onImageDownloaded()` that gets called when a certain event happens. like perhaps i'm downloading an image, and i want to trigger an event when the image downloads (and yes, i get that there is something called `AsyncTask` and also posting a runnable message from background thread, but for pedagogical reasons let's pretend the process could have been on the UI thread also). How does Android know to call the method `onImageDownloaded()` ? or rather, how do i specify that when an image gets downloaded, i want it to call my method `onImageDownloaded()` ?

i've read about broadcast intents, but that seems more of a system level and kind of over-doing it.

I know that when you make a button in the view, you can do

```
final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("MyActivity", "button is clicked");
    }
});
```

and it's almost like setting a "hook" to the button that calls the particular "onClick" when the click event happens.

in my particular case, how would i create a custom callback method upon actions "XYZ" ??

sorry for the long question, thanks for the patience to read and to try and understand it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to first learn what is callback:

> In computer programming, a callback is a reference to executable code,
>   or a piece of executable code, that is passed as an argument to other
>   code. This allows a lower-level software layer to call a subroutine
>   (or function) defined in a higher-level layer.

[Wickipedia: Callback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29)

To make our code more re-useable and optimize, we need call back.

Let's say: you have a `class` which downloads data from the internet. If you want to make the class more re-useable, you will define a `protocol` (any `class` construct) to whom it will inform. Later the `classes` which conforms to that protocol (or implements that protocol)can use the downloaded data accordingly.

Callbacks are made typically using `interface` keyword, but `abstract class` or a simple `class` can be used also.

[Here is simple illustration how to make and use our own callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7618705/593709).

Answer (score 2):

A simple example of what is going on:

```
XYZer xyzer=new XYZer();
xyzer.setXYZListener(new XYZListener() {

    public void onXYZ(View v) {
        Log.d("MyActivity", "XYZ happened");
    }
});

class XYZer
{
    XYZListener listener;
    void setXYZListener(XYZListener listener){this.listener=listener;}

    void test(View v)
    {
        if(listener!=null)listener.onXYZ(v);
    }
}
```

HTH. Sorry I haven't got time for a more long winded explanation, hopefully someone else will provide that.

Comment: thanks for the code, it helped demo a short example. and i understand you didn't have all the time in the world to provide a long-winded full detailed example. 

i upvoted your answer, but at first i didn't understand your code, because i still didn't understand the concept behind it because it was missing some components.

later on i found out that what happens (i.e. in android) is that basically you render a view; and then Android controls over exactly when that "onXYZ()" is called. so in your example you would need some instance to run the XYZer, like Android services for the views

Answer (score 1):

One way of achieving the callback mechanism is by using an Interface.

The following tutorials contains a nice example of a callback mechnanism.

http://about-android.blogspot.com/2010/02/create-custom-dialog.html .

have a look at the interface ReadyListener which has a single method

```
public void ready(String name);
```