# How to unit test an AsyncTask in android?

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, android-asynctask

I have a simple AsyncTask that performs some calculations. How can i unit test it?

Comment: check out the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295003/best-way-to-manage-the-progressdialog-from-asynctask/8317071#8317071) to see if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you'd need to test it asynchronously. If your code is in the doInBackground method, you could just call that method from your test class and assert something with the result when it returns.

Comment: @Shalmezad Then extend AsyncTask and create a new public method that calls the protected method there?

Comment: @Shalmezad `protected` is accessible in same package, thus following a convention of having tests in same package helps

Comment: @AivarasPrudnikovas Good catch and thanks for the correction. Must've mistaken Java's protected with C++'s protected 4 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

I had found the following example, I think you should check this out:
https://github.com/pivotal/RobolectricSample

Comment: try this please:https://github.com/android10/Inside_Android_Testing/tree/master/RobolectricSample