# getActionBar() works fine on devices/simulator but returns null in testcases

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-testing

Application supports `minSdk=14` and have `ActionBar` on every `Activity`.

Application works fine since a long time and shows `ActionBar` on every `Activity`. Now I am writing Android `JUnit` `Testcases` but it gives `NullPointException` on line

> ```
>   getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
> ```

The bottom line is `getActionBar()` works on devices but returns `null` during test cases. If I remove the line then testcases are fine.

Here's how activity looks like.

> ```
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {      
>       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>       setContentView(R.layout.activity_order);
>       getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
> ```
>
> // other stuff under it
>
> ```
>  }
> ```

`JUnits` are simple Android JUnit Testcases without any framework.

> ```
> public class OrderActivityTest extends ActivityUnitTestCase<OrderActivity> {   
>
>   private OrderActivity activity;
>
>   public OrderActivityTest() {        
>           super(OrderActivity.class);   
>     }   
>
>     protected void setUp() throws Exception {
>          super.setUp();
>          Intent intent = new Intent(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext(),OrderActivity.class);
>          startActivity(intent, null, null);
>          activity = getActivity();
>     }
>
>   public void testPreConditions() {
>          assertTrue(activity != null);    
>      }  
>  }
> ```

And finally here's the exception while running test case.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.name.OrderActivity.onCreate(OrderActivity.java:176)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at android.test.ActivityUnitTestCase.startActivity(ActivityUnitTestCase.java:158)
at com.example.name.test.OrderActivityTest.setUp(OrderActivityTest.java:23)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
```

Line 176 is `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

Comment: Have you resolve this problem?

Comment: @Kolchuga No. I haven't.

Comment: @Sharj  Is your activity extending Activity, or something else - like FragmentActivity or ActionBarSherlock?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky It extends Activity.

Answer (score 0):

getActionBar() is probably returning null here. The title needs to be visible, make sure you don't have things like this there:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar
```

This would cause an error in getActionBar() being null.

Comment: I don't. I have @android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar theme. I do see ActionBar, just not in JUnit testcase it's null.

Comment: have you seen this? http://blog.perpetumdesign.com/2011/08/strange-case-of-dr-action-and-mr-bar.html

Comment: Yes, I did read that couple of times. Never had problem with it before just having problem with testing Activity with native ActionBar.