# AsyncTask Return Result

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am currently having trouble getting a value from an AsyncTask that gets data from a JSON connection. I have looked at a few examples, but mostly I have only seen posting results from AsyncTask.

First I have an object called Dog that only has a String, Name. I am trying to get the Name of the dog from the server.
Using the following code in my oncreate, I start the DogAsyncTask while assing in an URL called n and a Dog d_in.

```
    Dog d_in = new Dog("DogName");
    DogAsyncTask task = new DogAsyncTask(d_in);
    String n = "www.dog.com";
    task.execute(n);
    Log.e("Out", d_in.getName());
```

My AsyncTask is as follows:

```
 private class DogAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    Dog d = null;

    DogAsyncTask(Dog d){
        this.d = d;
    }

    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        d.setName(result);
        Log.e("Dog", d.getName());
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(AsyncTestActivity.this, "Loading...", "Data is Loading...");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... name) {
        //Go to url = name and then gets String below.
        String outfromjson = "new dog name";  //This will be a function that gets a name from JSON
        return outfromjson;
    }
}
```

I tried using something like
    Log.e("Out", task.d.getName());
but I keep getting the default name of the dog which is "DogName". How to I carry values out of AsyncTask?

Comment: [Have a look at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7618705/593709)

Comment: yes;
Log.e("Dog", d.getName()) shows the dogname as "new dog name"

Comment: Thanks for your help Adil, I didn't understand you response when I read it before but after trying it it worked out well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, The thing what is happening here is:

You want to pass `Dog` as reference (`pointers` as in C / C++ / Objective-C),
and you want to reflect change in original variable using other variable.

but keep in mind that Java doesn't pass object by reference, Java passes objects by value (only value is transferred, another object is created and assigned value).

So what you can do is you can assign that result-holder object again as a value to the original object.

Comment: Would you know how to get the result (Object data) out of the new DataDownloadListener()?

Comment: as I've implemented [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7618705/593709), I pass the data to `listener.downloadedSuccessfully(data)` and in implementation I get that data where I've commented `// handler result`, you can get the result there.. :)

Comment: I am still a little confused. In my activity, after the last line: getdata.execute("");, I want to return data; upwards out of a function, how can I get Object data from dataDownloadedSuccessfully(Object data) and return it outwards?

Comment: You can set that Object data to any class level variable. or you can set Text to any TextView or manipulate as you wish..

Comment: even we can use our own interface to get return value from asyncTask.
i have just posted example for the same on my blog.
You can refer it on below link with Sample Code.
[http://smartphonebysachin.blogspot.in/2012/11/how-to-return-value-from-async-task-in.html]http://smartphonebysachin.blogspot.in/2012/11/how-to-return-value-from-async-task-in.html

Comment: @SachinShelke: your solution is identical to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7618705/593709), see the note and comments on this post to have some idea about assigning another listener to `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following,

Declare and implement an interface in your activity and then use it's methods as a callback from the onPostExecute method.