# How do I get data (and an event) from a thread into the main service (UI) thread's event loop?

Tags: android, multithreading

I have an async task which runs in a separate `Thread` of my `Service`.

I'd like to get the result of this task back into the main UI thread and wake up the main UI thread to deal with it.

What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: [Have a look at this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7618705/593709).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *correct* way of doing this with an `AsyncTask` is to return the result back to the UI thread in the `onPostExecute` method.

There are tons of examples of `AsyncTask` implementations on Stack Overflow so I'm not going to link to any of them. If you would like an example *specifically* tailored to your `AsyncTask`, include the relevant code in your question.