# How to execute multiple functions at the same time in an AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, google-translate

I have an asyncTask Class which is called whenever the user taps a "Send" button from an `AppCompatActivity`. In the `doInBackground` method of my AsyncTask, I translate a string into 30 languages using Google Translate API. The problem is, it takes some time for each string to be translated into each language. I feel like it would be a better approach to run all of these functions at the same time by multithreading.

Each time a `try` and `catch` is its own set of instructions to translate a string into 1 language. This approach is too slow.

**Here is my doInBackground Function:**

```
 @Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

    translate = TranslateOptions.newBuilder().setApiKey("GOOGLE_API_KEY").build().getService();

     /*ENGLISH TO ARABIC*/     

    try {
                Translation translation =
                        translate.translate(
                                MY_STRING,
                                Translate.TranslateOption.sourceLanguage("en"),
                                Translate.TranslateOption.targetLanguage("ar"));
                parseObject.put("data0", translation.getTranslatedText());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                parseObject.put("data0", MY_STRING + " " + mContext.getString(R.string.translationfailed));

            }

      /*English to Chinese*/
 try {
                Translation
                        translation =
                        translate.translate(
                                MY_STRING,
                                Translate.TranslateOption.sourceLanguage("en"),
                                Translate.TranslateOption.targetLanguage("zh-CN"));
                parseObject.put("data1", translation.getTranslatedText());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                parseObject.put("data1", MY_STRING + " " + mContext.getString(R.string.translationfailed));

            }

  /*28 More languages run...*/

 /*Then, Save Data into server*/

  parseObject.saveinBackground();

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Try this link :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068984/running-multiple-asynctasks-at-the-same-time-not-possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Multi Thread. AsyncTask is good for Short time & light operation.
[read this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/index.html)

download and test sample code.

also you can run one AsyncTask and Pass same parameters for each lanuage.
but for multiple AsyncTask

```
class doSomethingInBack extends AsyncTask(String, String, String){}
```

[See this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900834/how-to-pass-variables-in-and-out-of-asynctasks)

this is Thread Sample
    class PhotoDecodeRunnable implements Runnable {
    /*
    * Defines the code to run for this task.
    */
    @Override
    public void run() {
    // Moves the current Thread into the background
    android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);

```
/*
* Stores the current Thread in the PhotoTask instance,
*  that the instance
* can interrupt the Thread.
*/
try {
Translation translation =
translate.translate(
MY_STRING,
Translate.TranslateOption.sourceLanguage("en"),
Translate.TranslateOption.targetLanguage("ar"));
parseObject.put("data0", translation.getTranslatedText());
} catch (Exception e) {
parseObject.put("data0", MY_STRING + " " + mContext.getString(R.string.translationfailed));
}

/*English to Chinese*/
 try {
Translation
translation =
translate.translate(
MY_STRING,
Translate.TranslateOption.sourceLanguage("en"),
Translate.TranslateOption.targetLanguage("zh-CN"));
parseObject.put("data1", translation.getTranslatedText());
} catch (Exception e) {
parseObject.put("data1", MY_STRING + " " + mContext.getString(R.string.translationfailed));
}

}
}
```

Comment: This link is broken for me.

Comment: this one https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/index.html

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I will mark accepted answer if you provide example code for me for my situation.

Comment: copy and paste all your try{}catch(){} functions to thread it s super easy @grant

Comment: Please give me an example.

Comment: Do I put all of my try{}calc{} functions in 1 thread or does each one get its own thread? @Elias Fazel

Comment: check my new solution >> pass data to Async. it means run AsynTask multiple time with different value. this might be easier to implement @grant

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer:

```
ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
        parserTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, result);
    }else{
        parserTask.execute(result);
    }
```

Comment: What dis this do? And where do I put my functions?

Comment: Allows you to run multiple tasks at the same time/ put the code when u call methode asyncTask.execute.
In my exemple parserTask is the instance of Class extends AsyncTask