# Getting string from mainactivity to an activity that extends AsyncTask, using edittext

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I need to pass a string to AsyncTask by taking an input from MainActivity to put that string to an url which is present in the AsyncTask. I have two activities, one is MainActivity and another is fetchData activity. My MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button click;
EditText text;
public  static TextView data;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    data = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fetcheddata);
    text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String theText = text.getText().toString();
    click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {fetchData process = new fetchData();process.execute();}});}}
```

And my fetchData Activity code goes like this:

```
public class fetchData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>  {
String data ="";
String dataParsed = "";
String singleParsed ="";
String uriString;
@Overrideprotected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://fuelpriceindia.herokuapp.com/price?city=mumbai");
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        while(line != null){
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            data = data + line;}
        JSONObject JO = new JSONObject(data);
         }} 
       catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }return null;}@Override protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid){super.onPostExecute(aVoid);MainActivity.data.setText(this.dataParsed);}}`
```

I want to pass a string to get any city name in the url 
`URL url = new URL("http://fuelpriceindia.herokuapp.com/price?city=mumbai");`
city=any city name got from the edit text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variables in and out of AsyncTasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900834/how-to-pass-variables-in-and-out-of-asynctasks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to pass data to `AsyncTask`.

1. create a constructor with parameter in your `AysncTask` like -

   ```
     public void fetchData(String city) {

     }
   ```
2. Pass value in parameter of `AsyncTask` like -

   ```
    fetchData process = new fetchData();
    process.execute(text.getText().toString()); // Pass parameter
   ```

In your `AsyncTask` get this value

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String...params) 
{
    String cityName = params[0];
    try {
    URL url = new URL("http://fuelpriceindia.herokuapp.com/price?city="+cityName);
      .......

}
```

Make sure to convert your

```
 public class fetchData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
```

into

```
 public class fetchData extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>
```

Comment: Thank you very very much. That saved my day. You are just awesome.

Comment: This might be silly question but how can I do that @Rahul

Comment: Oh got it @Rahul