# AsyncTask - Return a String in postExecute to the Activity, which started the Async Task without blocking the UI Thread

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, return

I have an Activity, which starts an AsyncTask with an Implemented process dialog. That works fine! But i want to get a String return when the asyncTask has finished. So i have to return something in the onPostExecute - Method.
That result(string) i want to grab in the Activity, which started the AsyncTask.
I do not want to use .get() because it blocks the UI thread.

What do i have to write into onPostExecute and the Activity grab the string from doInBackground?

Thank you for any kind of help to solve this problem ;)

Now with Code:

```
class BgDL extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    String finishString="";
    private Context context;

    ProgressDialog pdialog;

    public BgDL(Context cxt) {  //get the context (usually "this" from Activity / otherwise progressdialog wont show up!
        context = cxt;
        pdialog = new ProgressDialog(context);

    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        OutputStream output;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            if (strings[1]=="toString") { // write byte to string  if a file is not given
                baos= new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                output = new DataOutputStream(baos);
            } else { //otherwise to string
                output = new FileOutputStream(strings[1]);
            }
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
       }
       output.flush();
       output.close();
       input.close();
       if (strings[1]=="toString") { 
           finishString = baos.toString(); //
       } // only write byte to string if a file is not given
    } catch (Exception e) {log.d("ex",e.toString());
    }
    return finishString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pdialog.setTitle("Please wait");
        pdialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pdialog.setMax(100);
        pdialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        pdialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        pdialog.setProgress(progress[0]);

    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String...finishString) {
        pdialog.dismiss();//!!!!!!!!!finishString i want to pass over to my Activity, which started this asynctask with .execute();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a class in your project which extends activity as shown below:

```
public class SomeClass extends Activity
{
    public void dataFromPostExecute(String data) 
    {
        System.out.println("in mainactivity");
    }
}
```

If you want a single thread for every activity, just create a class which extends 
[Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)

```
public class Async extends Application
{
private Socket globalSocket;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        //socket = null;
    }

    public Socket getglobalSocket() 
    {
        return globalSocket;
    }

    public void setGlobalSocket(Socket globalSocket) 
    {
        this.globalSocket = globalSocket;
    }
}
```

In your socket class which extends Asynctask do the following:

```
public SocketClass extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
{
    Async app;
    private SomeClass t_act;
    public SocketClass(SomeClass sct) 
    {
        t_act = sct;
        this.con = tst;
        app= ((Async)sct.getApplicationContext());
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String data)
    {
        t_act.dataFromPostExecute(data);
    }
}
```

Then, in your activity extend SomeClass and do as shown below:

```
public class Activity1 extends SomeClass
{
    public void dataFromPostExecute(String data)
        {
            //do whatever you want. "data" of this method contains the values from                                     
              postexecute()
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your return value from doInBackground() is you formal in onPostExecute().
So you should just be able to pass it in.

Comment: i mean something like AsyncTask a = new AsyncTask(Context); a.execute(Input); and the result after execute has finished i want to save. Something like String test = a.execute(Input) , but yes i know after execute is called async task ist not finished! So how to get the return of that AsyncTask, when it is finished!

Comment: I just upvoted @hawaii's answer. He's doing the exact thing I suggest, but provided a sample.

Answer (score 1):

> What do i have to write into onPostExecute and the Activity grab the
>   string from doInBackground?

When you are using `AsyncTask` then you can update your `UI` only on `onProgressUpdate` and `onPostExecute` method.

Your `doInBackground()` method returns some data and these data is going to `onPostExecute` method(it depends also how your generic are declared). 

Generally, there is no another approaches how to do it.

You meant this:

```
AsyncTask a = new AsyncTask(Context);
a.execute(Input);
```

First means that your constructor looks like

```
public MyAsync(Context c) {
   this.c = c;
}
```

Second means that you declared your first generic type(assumption Input param is `String`) as

```
private class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
  //...
}
```

And you want to update `UI` with `String` that returns `doInBackground()` method and merely place is `onPostExecute` method with `IN` parameter `String` that returns `doInBackground()`.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String stringReturnedFromDoInBackground) 
{
   // some work
}
```

So if you want to do it in different way, change your application logic and use for example `ResultReceiver` with `IntentService`.

Comment: first and second yes, maybe i just post the code so i will get easier to explain, because i did not fully understand you :/

Comment: it means that your data(returned from doInBackground) can be processed only in onPostExecute.

Comment: oh, there is no other chance?