# Call AsyncTask from another class

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In an existing app I have an activity with an inner class which extends AsyncTask, this looks like the following:

```
public class Activity_1 extends BaseActivity {
    ....
    new async().execute();
    ...

    public class asyncextends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        protected String doInBackground(Void... progress) { ... }
        protected void onPreExecute() { ... }
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) { ... }
    }
}
```

Now, I need to call the same doInBackground-method from another activity, but the `onPostExecute()` of the this inner class operates on some local UI variables and hence it's not possible to use it from outside the clas.
Is there any way I can call this AsyncTask, and just override the `onPostExecute` and`onPreExecute`-method, or shall I create yet another inner-class in the other activity, do the same background thing (of course move it to common utility-class or something), etc...?

Comment: [What about such solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7618705/593709)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can make a separate abstract package private class, extending `AsyncTask` and implementing `doInBackground()` method:

```
abstract class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    @Override
    final protected String doInBackground(Void... progress) { 
        // do stuff, common to both activities in here
    }
}
```

And in your activities just inherit from `MyAsyncTask` (new class probably should be private, by the way), implementing `onPostExecute()` and `onPreExecute()` methods:

```
public class Activity_1 extends BaseActivity {

    ...
    new Async1().execute();
    ...

    private class Async1 extends MyAsyncTask {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){ 
            // Activity 1 GUI stuff
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // Activity 1 GUI stuff
        }
    }
}
```

If `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` contain some common actions as well, you can apply the following pattern:

```
abstract class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    public interface MyAsyncTaskListener {
       void onPreExecuteConcluded();
       void onPostExecuteConcluded(String result);  
    }

    private MyAsyncTaskListener mListener;

    final public void setListener(MyAsyncTaskListener listener) {
       mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    final protected String doInBackground(Void... progress) { 
        // do stuff, common to both activities in here
    }

    @Override
    final protected void onPreExecute() {
        // common stuff
        ...
        if (mListener != null) 
            mListener.onPreExecuteConcluded();
    }

    @Override
    final protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // common stuff
        ...
        if (mListener != null) 
            mListener.onPostExecuteConcluded(result);
    }
}
```

and use it in your activity as following:

```
public class Activity_1 extends BaseActivity {

    ...
    MyAsyncTask aTask = new MyAsyncTask();
    aTask.setListener(new MyAsyncTask.MyAsyncTaskListener() {
       @Override
       void onPreExecuteConcluded() {
           // gui stuff
       }

       @Override
       void onPostExecuteConcluded(String result) {
           // gui stuff
       }
    });
    aTask.execute();
    ...
}
```

You can also have your `Activity` implement `MyAsyncTaskListener` as well:

```
public class Activity_1 extends BaseActivity implements MyAsyncTask.MyAsyncTaskListener {
    @Override
    void onPreExecuteConcluded() {
        // gui stuff
    }

    @Override
    void onPostExecuteConcluded(String result) {
       // gui stuff
    }

    ...
    MyAsyncTask aTask = new MyAsyncTask();
    aTask.setListener(this);
    aTask.execute();
    ...

}
```

I wrote the code from the head, so it might contain errors, but it should illustrate the idea.

Comment: Exactly something like this I was looking for. Will try to implement it first thing tomorrow morning.

Comment: Great answer! But I can't work out why I'm getting the following for `MyAsyncTask aTask = new MyAsyncTask();` _Cannot instantiate the type MySyncTask_ Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Smittey must be a copy-paste error - the second implementation of MyAsyncTask shouldn't be abstract

Comment: Awesome examples, especially the listener implementation. Worked perfectly in my current project! :)

Answer (score 16):

Its so simple just Simply build an object of main class and than call the inner class like this

```
 OuterMainClass outer = new OuterMainClass();
       outer.new InnerAsyncClass(param)
         .execute();
```

this answer is too late to help you but hope it help others.

Thanks

Comment: Glad it helped someone  :)

Comment: hey can you do me a favor.. it worked really fine but now i have to return value to caller class and how should i do that..? i called Asynctask class from another class . so i want to get result of asyncTask in that caller class. do you know anyway to how to do it.? thanks  :)

Comment: Call a method of your caller class from onPostExecute() method of Asynctask

Comment: yeah you are right . that will work but if i want to implement that for more than one class.?

Comment: make a static object thn pass it different values from different classes and onPostExc.. method check the value of that variable in onPostEx.. method, from there you get to know that which class called it thn simply from "if" statements call the appropriate method.

Comment: yeah i also thought about that to check through if conditions that from which class it is being called. but i think that's not a proper way.  although i will do it that way. ;) thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

1.Create a constructor of AsynckTask in ClassOne.

2.Crate object or ClassOne by new keyword.

3.Call Async Task by object

```
ClassOne{

class AsyncParmas extends AsyncTask {

        public ADDloadGeofenceDetails() {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {


            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {

}
}

Class ClassTwo{
ClassOne obj= new ClassOne ();

                    obj.new AsyncParmas ().execute();
}
}
```

GoodLuck Who were facing problem.

Answer (score -1):

If we create one static method which is in one class and and will be execute in any class in doInBackground of AsyncTask we can easily update UI through same class and even in different class .

Comment: Give answers with concrete examples, just an FYI answer is not helpfull