# How to call AsynkTask from another Activity in android?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have a MainActivity contain a Action bar and a refresh button in action bar and MainActivity add   a Fragment called "Deal Listing" contain `listview`  which execute Url and Update some `Listview`  of fragment "Deal Listing" and a Fragment "Deal" which also execute URL and update `Listview` of "Deal" fragment.what I want when `fragment` "Deal Listing" added to MainActivity I want to refresh content of listview of  DealFragment on click refreshButon and when "deal" fragment added to MainActivity I want to refresh content of "Deal" fragment `listview` refreshButon .How do I do that

Here is code of **DealListing Fragment**:-

```
  private void init() {
        m_LoadMoreProgressView = (CircularProgressView) m_Main.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        m_LoadMoreProgressView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        m_n_FormImage = new int[]{
                R.drawable.amazon,
                R.drawable.whatsapp,
                R.drawable.zorpia,
                R.drawable.path,
                R.drawable.app_me,
                R.drawable.evernote,
                R.drawable.app_me};

        m_ListView = (ListView) m_Main.findViewById(R.id.dealList);


        sz_RecordCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DefaultRecordCount);// increment of record count
        sz_LastCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DeafalutLastCount);// increment of last count...

    }


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private String DealListing(String url) {
        InputStream inputStream;
        try {
            // 1. create HttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            // 2. make POST request to the given URL
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            String json;
            // 3. build jsonObject
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("agentCode", m_szMobileNumber);
            jsonObject.put("pin", m_szEncryptedPassword);
            jsonObject.put("recordcount", sz_RecordCount);
            jsonObject.put("lastcountvalue", sz_LastCount);
            //jsonObject.put("emailId", "nirajk1190@gmail.com");
            // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
            json = jsonObject.toString();
            System.out.println("Jsons:-" + json);
            // 5. set json to StringEntity
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
            // 6. set httpPost Entity
            httpPost.setEntity(se);
            // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            // 9. receive response as inputStream
            inputStream = entity.getContent();
            System.out.println("InputStream....:" + inputStream.toString());
            System.out.println("Response....:" + httpResponse.toString());

            StatusLine statusLine = httpResponse.getStatusLine();
            System.out.println("statusLine......:" + statusLine.toString());
            ////Log.d("resp_body", resp_body.toString());
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            // 10. convert inputstream to string
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                // 10. convert inputstream to string
                s_szresult = CJsonsResponse.convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
                //String resp_body =
            } else
                s_szresult = "Did not work!";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("resul.....:" + s_szresult);
        System.out.println("pin:" + m_szEncryptedPassword);
        System.out.println("recordCount:" + sz_RecordCount);
        System.out.println("LastCount:" + sz_LastCount);
        // 11. return s_szResult
        return s_szresult;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    private void getResponse() throws JSONException {// getting response from serevr ..................
        if (m_oResponseobject.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Transaction Successful")) {// server based condition


        } else if (m_oResponseobject.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Connection Not Available")) {//server based conditions
            CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "Connection Lost !", getActivity());
        } else if (m_oResponseobject.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Deal List Not Found")) {// serevr based conditions .....
            CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "No more deals available", getActivity());

        }
    }

    //  sending deal data to server and retreive response......
    class CDealDataSent extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        public CDealAppDatastorage item;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            m_ProgressView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            return DealListing(urls[0]);// sending data to server...

        }

        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {

            m_ProgressView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            try {
                m_oResponseobject = new JSONObject(result);// getting response from server
                JSONArray posts = m_oResponseobject.optJSONArray("dealList");


                for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(i);
                    item = new CDealAppDatastorage();
                    item.setM_szHeaderText(post.getString("dealname"));
                    item.setM_szsubHeaderText(post.getString("dealcode"));
                    item.setM_szDealValue(post.getString("dealvalue"));
                    item.setM_n_Image(m_n_FormImage[i]);
                    s_oDataset.add(item);

                }

                // LoadMore button
                Button btnLoadMore = new Button(getActivity());
                btnLoadMore.setText("LOAD MORE DEALS");
                btnLoadMore.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_boarder);
                btnLoadMore.setTextAppearance(getActivity(), android.R.style.TextAppearance_DeviceDefault_Small);
                btnLoadMore.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                btnLoadMore.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                if (!s_oDataset.isEmpty()) {
                    // Adding Load More button to lisview at bottom
                    m_ListView.addFooterView(btnLoadMore);
                    m_oAdapter = new CDealAppListingAdapter(getActivity(), s_oDataset);// create adapter object and add arraylist to adapter
                    m_ListView.setAdapter(m_oAdapter);//adding adapter to recyclerview
                    m_oAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    btnLoadMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }


                btnLoadMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        m_n_DefaultRecordCount = m_n_DefaultRecordCount + 5;// increment of record count by 5 on next load data
                        m_n_DeafalutLastCount = m_n_DeafalutLastCount + 5;// same here.....as above

                        sz_RecordCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DefaultRecordCount);// convert int value to string
                        sz_LastCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DeafalutLastCount);// convert int value to string /////
                        new DealNext().execute(m_DealListingURL);// POST DATA TO SERVER TO LOAD MORE DATA......
                    }
                });

                getResponse();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }

    //  sending data and receive reponse on second hit T LOAD MORE DATA  when show more Btn  clicked..............
    private class DealNext extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            m_LoadMoreProgressView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);// SHOW PROGRESS BAR
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            //My Background tasks are written here
            synchronized (this) {
                return DealListing(urls[0]);// POST DATA TO SERVER
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            m_LoadMoreProgressView.setVisibility(View.GONE);// DISMISS PROGRESS BAR..........
            try {
                m_oResponseobject = new JSONObject(result);// getting response from server
                final JSONArray posts = m_oResponseobject.optJSONArray("dealList");// GETTING DEAL LIST
                for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(i);// GETTING DEAL AT POSITION AT I
                    item = new CDealAppDatastorage();// object create of DealAppdatastorage
                    item.setM_szHeaderText(post.getString("dealname"));//getting deal name
                    item.setM_szsubHeaderText(post.getString("dealcode"));// getting deal code
                    item.setM_szDealValue(post.getString("dealvalue"));

                    if(!s_oDataset.contains(item)){
                        s_oDataset.add(item);
                    }

                }
                // get listview current position - used to maintain scroll position
                int currentPosition = m_ListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                m_oAdapter = new CDealAppListingAdapter(getActivity(), s_oDataset);
                m_ListView.setAdapter(m_oAdapter);
                // Setting new scroll position
                m_ListView.setSelectionFromTop(currentPosition + 1, 0);

                getResponse();// getting response from server.....and also here response based logics...


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Now this days i am using SwipeRefreshLayout it's easy to use just check it.http://www.androidhive.info/2015/05/android-swipe-down-to-refresh-listview-tutorial/

Comment: If you want to use the AsyncTask in another Activity, you'll need to pull `class CDealDataSent` out of the current class.

Comment: I am executing url sometime when Screen is open show blank that why I am using refresh

Comment: how to pull solution pls

Comment: Sadly, with the amount of code you've mixed together between the AsyncTask and the Activity variables, it would be difficult. Since you are dealing with JSON, I would recommend you consider using the Retrofit+Gson libraries to handle all the JSON and HTTP stuff for you.

Comment: ok.. if I execute Url in oncreate and set intially 10 response in listview and listview has a load more button when user click on load more it will again execute url and fetch 10 more details .How I refresh when on click refresh button

Comment: you can find a good example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545022/call-asynctask-from-another-class) your post seems duplicate of this question. so first search than ask.

Comment: Ok I have a Fragment called DealMainListing which contain two tab is that posible to add Toolbar with navigation drawer in that